# Testing in a page context

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, phantomjs, tableau-api

I need some guidance on how to run js unit tests in web page context.

I have a page where graphs will be drawn using a 3rd party JS library.
Also, there will be some filtering logic written by me - I want to test this piece.

The challenge I have is that I have to have a DOM present for this library to work, and I'm not quite sure how to run tests in this context.

It all looks something like this:

On a web page I have a div.
Then in JS file I will say

```
var drawing = DrawStuffIn(getElementByid("my-div"));
drawing.FilterBy(something);
var filteredItems = drawing.GetFilteredItems();
```

At this point I want to make sure that *filteredItems* contain what I expect.

I was looking at using PhantomJS and Jasmine, but not quite sure how to fit it all together.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options:

1. A headless browser (such as PhantomJS) (slow and powerful)
2. DOM emulation (such as jsdom) (fast but imperfect)

If you simply need a DOM environment in order for the library to work, but don't need it to work like the real DOM in every way, you can use DOM emulation, such as jsdom, which will be much quicker.

PhantomJS is essentially Chrome without a head, and you can write scripts and have them run in the Chrome context. Which you should pick depends on what you actually need to do. Mainly, does jsdom support the library and the functionality that you need to test?

You should provide more detail about what the sentence `At this point I want to make sure that filteredItems contain what I expect.` means. Are you going to be testing it for text content, or is it going to have images, drawings, or whatnot?

Comment: filteredItems are JS objects with some data.  I'm not sure how to run tests, though. So I render a page in PhantomJS, then what?  We used Jasmine as test framework, but i'm not sure if I can make it work for my case.